# retrieving a line of code after pressing the down-arrow key

Tags: r

If I type a line of R code at the cursor and press 'Enter' I can immediately retrieve that code by pressing the up-arrow key once.  However, if I am typing a line of code and accidentally press the down-arrow key once then that line of code disappears and I cannot retrieve it.  This is a minor, but ever-present annoyance, most frustrating when typing data into a vector.

Is there a way to retrieve a line of code after accidentally pressing the down-arrow key?

I am using a Windows machine and the R GUI found on my desktop immediately after installation... ...I think one of the questions during installation is whether I want a short-cut on my desktop, and I select 'yes'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is completely dependent on the GUI.  I believe (but am not certain) that RStudio, for example, preserves what you have typed.

While not a direct solution, what might be helpful is to use edit in an external window. I dont use windows, but I suspect if you hit `ctrl+n` you will get an editor in which you can then use `F5`  or `ctrl+R`  to execute that specific line.

Personally, I use Sublime Text 2, and `cmd+enter` gets my code executed at the console

Comment: Made an edit to your answer. `ctrl+Enter` does not execute the code in Windows R GUI. `ctrl+R` and `F5` does.

Comment: @djhurio, thanks!  (Annoyingly, when I went to accept your edit, it was marked as already rejected.  I corrected my answer)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  If I press ctrl+n nothing seems to happen.  I can look into this more tomorrow.

Comment: @MarkMiller, look for a `file > new document` or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I open R and click `File` then `New Script` in the R menu an editor will open.  I can type a line of R code in that editor.  Then I can highlight that line of code and press `Ctrl+R`, as mentioned in Ricardo Saporta's answer and djhurio's comment.  By pressing `Ctrl+R` that line of R code will execute.  The line of R code remains visible in the editor and seems safe from being lost even if I accidentally hit the down-arrow key.

Hopefully this builds on Ricardo Saporta's answer enough to warrant being posted as another answer, although I would not have figured this out without Ricardo's and djhurio's help.

P.S.

In retrospect, I see now this is what Ricardo meant in his second comment beneath his answer.